# Handling JNDI names in Jboss 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I'm using JBoss 4.Here I'm using jndi.properties file for handling all JNDI Names.But If i switchover from Jboss 4 Jboss 7,I could not handle those JNDI names.Is there is any way to handle JNDI names in Jboss 7.

I want to declare a new JNDI Variable in Jboss 7.

Comment: what does it mean to "handle jndi names"? you can use Java EE standard env-entries to declare JNDI variables, for example.